# Comparing two tables and displaying the result as a separate output

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables and the values like this, `

```
CREATE TABLE Location (ID int ,Location Varchar(500))
    INSERT INTO Location values (1,'Loc3'),(2,'Loc4'),(3,'Loc5'),(4,'Loc7')
    CREATE TABLE InputLocation (ID int ,Location Varchar(500))
    Insert into InputLocation values(1,'Loc1,Loc2,Loc3,Loc4,Loc5,Loc6')
```

I need to get the output by matching each values from table `Location` with table `InputLocation` and need to display the output whichever not matched with 2nd table, i.e `Loc1,Loc2,Loc6` , I have tried some code like this and it worked But i need even simpler code, Any help would be greatly appreciated

My code :

```
SELECT  STUFF((select ','+ Data.C1 
FROM   
(select 
  n.r.value('.', 'varchar(50)') AS C1
from InputLocation as T
cross apply (select cast('<r>'+replace(replace(Location,'&','&amp;'), ',', '</r><r>')+'</r>' as xml)) as S(XMLCol)
cross apply S.XMLCol.nodes('r') as n(r))  DATA
WHERE  data.C1 NOT IN (SELECT Location
                FROM   Location) for  xml path('')),1,1,'') As Output
```

Comment: what is the relation between both table.without relation it is not possible.Secondly you should technically make it clear that why you don't want to use xml path ?If it is performance related ,then sorry you are not covering your requirement properly in first place.Other way can be recursive CTE,but its performance is worst.

Comment: id is the relation

Comment: Performance is not first preference for me now

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion to avoid using slow XML Reader:

```
;with tmp(DataItem, Location) as (
select cast(LEFT(Location, CHARINDEX(',',Location+',')-1) as nvarchar(50)),
    cast(STUFF(Location, 1, CHARINDEX(',',Location+','), '') as nvarchar(50))
from [InputLocation]
union all
select cast(LEFT(Location, CHARINDEX(',',Location+',')-1) as nvarchar(50)),
    cast(STUFF(Location, 1, CHARINDEX(',',Location+','), '') as nvarchar(50))
from tmp
where Location > ''
)
select STUFF((SELECT ',' + x.Location
from (
select DataItem as Location from tmp
except Select Location from [Location]) x
FOR XML path('')), 1, 1, '') AS OUTPUT
```

Comment: I need it without xml path

Comment: And also if insert into InputLocation values(2,'Loc3,Loc4') then also i need as output

Comment: meaning it should check with second table

Answer (score 0):

your script is ok.

Another method will be to use SPLIT String as describe here.
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

use [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]

Suppose my comma seperated string won't be longer than 500 then in my custom UDF i make it 500 varchar instead of varchar(8000) in order to improve performance.

```
SELECT STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + Data.item
            FROM (
                SELECT il.ID
                    ,fn.item
                FROM @InputLocation IL
                CROSS APPLY (
                    SELECT *
                    FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit2K(il.Location, ',')
                    ) fn
                WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                        SELECT *
                        FROM @Location L
                        WHERE l.Location = fn.Item
                        )
                ) data
            FOR XML path('')
            ), 1, 1, '') AS
OUTPUT
```

Comment: And also if  insert into InputLocation values(2,'Loc3,Loc4') then also i need as output

Comment: meaning it should check with second table